# Delimiter like IFS in bash for tcsh?

Tags: shell, unix, tcsh

I need fix paths can contain spaces. I read it is possible use IFS in bash. Is there something for **tcsh**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\` delimiter in tcsh.

For example, if the directory you want to reach is called "My Directory", you should write it like this:

```
set mypath = "/usr/home/My\ Directory"
```